# Use of the backspace character with input() Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscripter

I added a newline character to an `input()` statement and now, when the user types a word, it's hidden as though it was a password.

As in this extract from my program:

```
     else:
        name = input("\nPlease enter the name of the son to delete: ")
        name = name.title()
        if name in names:
            del names[name]
            print("\nOK, deleted: The list is now ", names)
        else:
            print("I don't have that name")
```

I was just wondering if this is normal as I haven't, as of yet, managed to find any reference to it, or is it a 'glitch' which I've stumbled across?

I'm using Pyscripter 2.6(64 bit) along with Python 3.1.3

Comment: Python 3.5.1 on MacOS - cannot reproduce

Comment: Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu -  cannot reproduce

Comment: Works as expected in the Python 3.5.2 REPL and IPython 2.7.12 on my computer running macOS.

Comment: So if you remove the `'\n'` from the `input()` prompt, then the characters the user types appear as normal? I cannot reproduce in a Python 3.5.2 REPL on Ubuntu either.

Comment: Is this in a dialog box in Pyscripter?  There are lots of complaints about poor terminal IO support, see https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter/issues/311

Comment: It is indeed in a dialogue box. Maybe I would be better using a better editor/ Python's own. If I remove the \n the text appears as normal when typing into the dialogue box.

Comment: Switched over to Pycharm and the issue has vanished.